# Why is my table going over margins?

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

[image]

```
\begin{table}[H]
\small
\centering
\caption{Specification sheet for the distillation column DC-01}
\label{tab:dc spec sheet}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}}
\hline
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{p{17cm}}{Design intent: To remove dimethyl phosphate from phosphorous acid, the distillate stream is designed to have a composition of 98\% dimethyl phosphate, whilst the bottoms stream is designed to have a composition of 99.8\% phosphorous acid. The distillate stream will be sent to storage, whilst the bottoms stream will be split with one stream going to the flaker, and the other going to the blenders.}\\
\hline
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Specification} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Value}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Column type} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Packed column}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Column diameter} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{0.11 m top, 0.26 m bottom}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Column height} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{2.4 m}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Average column temperature} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{117 \degree{C}}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Average column pressure} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{0.1 bar}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Shell material} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Stainless steel 316 lined with PFA}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Shell thickness} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{4 mm top, 5 mm bottom}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Insulation} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Rockwool 160 (mineral wool)}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Vessel Support} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Skirt support}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Skirt thickness} & \multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{6 mm}\\
\hline
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{p{17cm}}{Internal flowrates and conditions}\\
\hline
\toprule
& Liquid (kg/h) & Vapour (kg/h) & Temp (\degree{C}) & Pres. (bar) & Density (kg/m$^3$)\\
\midrule
Feed & 1231.0 & - & 80 & 0.1 & 1520\\
Overhead vapour & - & 43.6 & 104 & 0.1 & 0.39\\
Reflux liquid & 21.7 & - & 40 & 0.1 & 1323\\
Top product & 21.9 & - & 40 & 0.1 & 1323\\
Bottom product & 1209.1 & - & 130 & 0.1 & 1525\\
\hline
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Specification} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Value}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Packing type} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Mellapak\texttrademark\ 250Y}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Packing material} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Stainless steel 316L}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Number of stages} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{6 (excluding reboiler and condenser)}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Feed location} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Stage 3}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Packing size} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{10 mm top, 25 mm bottom}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{\% Flood} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{70}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{$\Delta$P/zone} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{0.0004 bar/m}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{$\Delta$P column} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{0.001 bar}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{HETP} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{0.4 m}\\
\hline
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{p{17cm}}{Condenser CON-01}\\
\hline
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Specification} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Value}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Condenser type} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Shell and tube}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Cooling fluid} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Water}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Heat exchange area} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{0.33 m$^2$}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Number of tubes} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{3}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Length} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{1.97 m}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Shell diameter} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{0.1 m}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Number of baffles} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{19}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Baffle spacing} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{0.1 m}\\
\hline
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{p{17cm}}{Reboiler RB-01}\\
\hline
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Specification} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Value}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Reboiler type} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Forced circulation}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Thermal fluid} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{Steam}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Heat exchange area} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{5.45 m$^2$}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Number of tubes} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{28}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Length} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{2.44 m}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Shell diameter} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{0.25 m}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Number of baffles} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{23}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{8.5cm}}{Baffle spacing} & \multicolumn{3}{m{8.5cm}}{0.1 m}\\
\bottomrule
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: table: standard tables and multicolumn... . colors: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and `\rowcolors{2}{blue!15}{white}`

Comment: Well, how wide is your text block? You are aware that you've made the table more than 17cm wide, due to the width of the `p` columns in the `\multicolumn`?

Comment: margins are 2cm so text block should be 17cm right? It was fine for the first part (design intent block) but went off after that.

Comment: Got it to work, didn't realise it would start text block at the margin. Changed to 15 cm and now its perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `ltablex` which combines  `longtable` and `tabularx`. I need
 only 2 X columns. This simplifies the code used for the table. I also load `siunitx` to align numerical values by their decimal dot. The rows with 6 columns are obtained as a `tabular*` environment nested in a `\multicolumn`. I deleted all `\hlines`, and replaced `\toprule`s inside the table (which have no spacing above) with `\midrule`s  of the same thickness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage[showframe, hmargin=2cm]{geometry}%
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{ltablex, caption, float, booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}

    \begin{document}

\small\keepXColumns\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\label{tab:dc spec sheet}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}%{p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}p{2.8cm}}
\caption{Specification sheet for the distillation column DC-01}
\label{tab:dc spec sheet}\\
\toprule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{Design intent: To remove dimethyl phosphate from phosphorous acid, the distillate stream is designed to have a composition of 98\,\% dimethyl phosphate, whilst the bottoms stream is designed to have a composition of 99.8\% phosphorous acid. The distillate stream will be sent to storage, whilst the bottoms stream will be split with one stream going to the flaker, and the other going to the blenders.}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
Specification & Value\\
\midrule
Column type & Packed column\\
Column diameter & 0.11 m top, 0.26 m bottom\\
Column height & 2.4 m\\
Average column temperature & \SI{117}{\celsius}\\
Average column pressure & 0.1 bar\\
Shell material & Stainless steel 316 lined with PFA\\
Shell thickness & 4 mm top, 5 mm bottom\\
Insulation & Rockwool 160 (mineral wool)\\
Vessel Support & Skirt support\\
Skirt thickness & 6 mm\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{Internal flowrates and conditions}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lS[table-format=4.1]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=1.1]S[table-format=4.2]}%{*{6}{p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-2\tabcolsep)/6\relax}}}
&{Liquid (kg/h)} & {Vapour (kg/h)} & {Temp (\si{\celsius})} & {Pres. (bar)} & {Density (kg/m$^3$)}\\
\midrule
Feed & 1231.0 &{–} & 80 & 0.1 & 1520\\
Overhead vapour &{–} & 43.6 & 104 & 0.1 & 0.39\\
Reflux liquid & 21.7 &{–} & 40 & 0.1 & 1323\\
Top product & 21.9 &{–} & 40 & 0.1 & 1323\\
Bottom product & 1209.1 &{–} & 130 & 0.1 & 1525\\
\end{tabular*}
}\\%
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
Specification & Value\\
\midrule
Packing type & Mellapak\texttrademark\ 250Y\\
Packing material & Stainless steel 316L\\
Number of stages & 6 (excluding reboiler and condenser)\\
Feed location & Stage 3\\
Packing size & 10 mm top, 25 mm bottom\\
\% Flood & 70\\
$\Delta$P/zone & 0.0004 bar/m\\
$\Delta$P column & 0.001 bar\\
HETP & 0.4 m\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{Condenser CON-01}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
Specification & Value\\
\midrule
Condenser type & Shell and tube\\
Cooling fluid & Water\\
Heat exchange area & 0.33 m$^2$\\
Number of tubes & 3\\
Length & 1.97 m\\
Shell diameter & 0.1 m\\
Number of baffles & 19\\
Baffle spacing & 0.1 m\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{Reboiler RB-01}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
Specification & Value\\
\midrule
Reboiler type & Forced circulation\\
Thermal fluid & Steam\\
Heat exchange area & 5.45 m$^2$\\
Number of tubes & 28\\
Length & 2.44 m\\
Shell diameter & 0.25 m\\
Number of baffles & 23\\
Baffle spacing & 0.1 m\\
\bottomrule
\hline
\end{tabularx}    

    \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your MWE I made the following changes:

- use `\tabularx` for table environments. With it the table is fit to the width of page
- use `siunitx` for all units in table
- main table has only two columns
- part of table with 6 columns is set as nested table
- remove rows, which repeat "Specification" and "Value"
- define some new commands for simplify typing of table

With this changes table can fit in one page:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=2cm]{geometry}

 \newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
\newcommand\mcpp[1]{\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{#1}}
 \newcommand\mct[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\small
\centering
\caption{Specification sheet for the distillation column DC-01}
    \label{tab:dc spec sheet}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \toprule
\mcpp{Design intent: To remove dimethyl phosphate from phosphorous acid, the distillate stream is designed to have a composition of 98\% dimethyl phosphate, whilst the bottoms stream is designed to have a composition of 99.8\% phosphorous acid. The distillate stream will be sent to storage, whilst the bottoms stream will be split with one stream going to the flaker, and the other going to the blenders.}      \\
    \midrule[1pt]
Specification               & Value                                 \\
    \midrule
Column type                 & Packed column                         \\
Column diameter             & \SI{0.11}{m} top, \SI{0.26}{m} bottom \\
Column height               & \SI{2.4}{m}                           \\
Average column temperature  & \SI{117}{\degreeCelsius}              \\
Average column pressure     & 0.1 bar                               \\
Shell material              & Stainless steel 316 lined with PFA    \\
Shell thickness             & \SI{4}{mm} top, \SI{5}{mm} bottom     \\
Insulation                  & Rockwool 160 (mineral wool)           \\
Vessel Support              & Skirt support                         \\
Skirt thickness             & \SI{6}{mm}                            \\  
    \midrule[1pt]
\mcpp{Internal flow rates and conditions}                           \\
    \midrule[1pt]
\mct{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{0.3\linewidth}
                             S[table-format=4.2]
                             S[table-format=2.1]
                             S[table-format=3.0]
                             S[table-format=1.1]
                             S[table-format=4.2]
                             }
                &   \mcx{Liquid (kg/h)}
                            &  \mcx{Vapour (kg/h)}
                                    &   \mcx{Temperature (\si{\degreeCelsius})}
                                            &   \mcx{Presure (bar)}
                                                    &   \mcx{Density (\si{kg/m^3})} \\
    \midrule[1pt]
Feed            & 1231.0    & {--}  & 80    & 0.1   & 1520  \\
Overhead vapour & {--}      & 43.6  & 104   & 0.1   & 0.39  \\
Reflux liquid   & 21.7      & {--}  & 40    & 0.1   & 1323  \\
Top product     & 21.9      & {--}  & 40    & 0.1   & 1323  \\
Bottom product  & 1209.1    & {--}  & 130   & 0.1   & 1525  \\
\end{tabularx}  
    }                                                               \\
    \midrule[1pt]
Specification               & Value                                 \\
    \midrule
Packing type                & Mellapak\texttrademark\ 250Y          \\
Packing material            & Stainless steel 316L                  \\
Number of stages            & 6 (excluding reboiler and condenser)  \\
Feed location               & Stage 3                               \\
Packing size                & \SI{10}{mm} top, \SI{25}{mm} bottom   \\
\% Flood                    & 70                                    \\
$\Delta$P/zone              & \SI{0.0004}{\bar/m}                   \\
$\Delta$P column            & \SI{0.001}{\bar}                      \\
HETP                        & \SI{0.4}{m}                           \\
    \midrule[1pt]
\mcpp{Condenser CON-01}                                             \\
%    \midrule[1pt]
%Specification               & Value                                 \\
    \midrule
Condenser type              & Shell and tube                        \\
Cooling fluid               & Water                                 \\
Heat exchange area          & \SI{0.33}{\cubic\metre}               \\
Number of tubes             &  3                                    \\
Length                      & \SI{1.97}{m}                          \\
Shell diameter              & \SI{0.1}{m}                           \\
Number of baffles           & 19                                    \\
Baffle spacing              & \SI{0.1}{m}                           \\
    \midrule[1pt]
\mcpp{Reboiler RB-01}                                               \\
%    \midrule[1pt]
%Specification               & Value                                 \\
    \midrule
Reboiler type               & Forced circulation                    \\
Thermal fluid               & Steam                                 \\
Heat exchange area          & \SI{5.45}{\square\metre}              \\
Number of tubes             & 28                                    \\
Length                      & \SI{2.44}{m}                          \\
Shell diameter              & \SI{0.25}{m}                          \\
Number of baffles           & 23                                    \\
Baffle spacing              & \SI{0.1}{m}                           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Above code can be used also with `ltablex` as suggest *Bernard* in his answer. In this case you can increase font size to `\normalsize`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a `tabularx` environment, with width set to `\textwidth` and five columns of type `X`, instead of a `tabular` environment. Note that the other column widths employed inside the `tabularx` environment are not absolute but are calculated relative to `\textwidth`. With this solution, it's *not* necessary to reduce the font size used in the table (via a `\small`directive, say).

Observe, furthermore, that I've dispensed with all `\hline` directives and have inserted a bit of vertical whitespace (via `\addlinespace`) in selected locations. I've also reorganized the header material. In particular, since the "Design intent" stuff seems to be a general legend (or introduction) and doesn't seem to belong inside the tabular part, I've placed it above the `\begin{tabularx}` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry} % based on a comment by the OP
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,siunitx,caption,calc}
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,labelfont=bf}

\newlength\mylen % set up a special length variable
\setlength\mylen{0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep} % usable width for 3-column material
\newcolumntype{P}{@{}p{\mylen}}
\newcolumntype{Q}{p{\mylen}@{}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{3}{#1}{#2}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\setcounter{table}{28} % just for this example :-)

\begin{table}[p!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

\caption{Specification sheet for the distillation column DC-01}
\label{tab:dc spec sheet}

Design intent: To remove dimethyl phosphate from phosphorous acid, the 
distillate stream is designed to have a composition of 98\%~dimethyl 
phosphate, whilst the bottoms stream is designed to have a composition of 
99.8\%~phosphorous acid. The distillate stream will be sent to storage, 
whilst the bottoms stream will be split with one stream going to the flaker, 
and the other going to the blenders.

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{5}{X} @{}}
\addlinespace
\toprule
\mc{P}{Specification} & \mc{Q}{Value}\\
\midrule
\mc{P}{Column type}     & \mc{Q}{Packed column}\\
\mc{P}{Column diameter} & \mc{Q}{0.11 m top, 0.26 m bottom}\\
\mc{P}{Column height}   & \mc{Q}{2.4 m}\\
\mc{P}{Average column temperature} & \mc{Q}{\SI{117}{\celsius}}\\
\mc{P}{Average column pressure} & \mc{Q}{0.1 bar}\\
\mc{P}{Shell material}  & \mc{Q}{Stainless steel 316 lined with PFA}\\
\mc{P}{Shell thickness} & \mc{Q}{4 mm top, 5 mm bottom}\\
\mc{P}{Insulation}      & \mc{Q}{Rockwool 160 (mineral wool)}\\
\mc{P}{Vessel Support}  & \mc{Q}{Skirt support}\\
\mc{P}{Skirt thickness} & \mc{Q}{6 mm}\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
& \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{Internal flowrates and conditions}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-6}
& Liquid (kg/h) & Vapour (kg/h) & Temp (\si{\celsius}) 
& Pres.\ (bar)  & Density (kg/m$^3$)\\
\midrule
Feed            & 1231.0 & --   & 80  & 0.1 & 1520\\
Overhead vapour & --     & 43.6 & 104 & 0.1 & 0.39\\
Reflux liquid   & 21.7   & --   & 40  & 0.1 & 1323\\
Top product     & 21.9   & --   & 40  & 0.1 & 1323\\
Bottom product  & 1209.1 & --   & 130 & 0.1 & 1525\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace\addlinespace
\mc{P}{Specification}    & \mc{Q}{Value}\\
\midrule
\mc{P}{Packing type}     & \mc{Q}{Mellapak\texttrademark\ 250Y}\\
\mc{P}{Packing material} & \mc{Q}{Stainless steel 316L}\\
\mc{P}{Number of stages} & \mc{Q}{6 (excluding reboiler and condenser)}\\
\mc{P}{Feed location}    & \mc{Q}{Stage 3}\\
\mc{P}{Packing size}     & \mc{Q}{10 mm top, 25 mm bottom}\\
\mc{P}{\% Flood}         & \mc{Q}{70}\\
\mc{P}{$\Delta$P/zone}   & \mc{Q}{0.0004 bar/m}\\
\mc{P}{$\Delta$P column} & \mc{Q}{0.001 bar}\\
\mc{P}{HETP}             & \mc{Q}{0.4 m}\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{Condenser CON-01}\\
%%\toprule
\mc{P}{Specification}      & \mc{Q}{Value}\\
\midrule
\mc{P}{Condenser type}     & \mc{Q}{Shell and tube}\\
\mc{P}{Cooling fluid}      & \mc{Q}{Water}\\
\mc{P}{Heat exchange area} & \mc{Q}{\SI{0.33}{\meter\squared}}\\
\mc{P}{Number of tubes}    & \mc{Q}{3}\\
\mc{P}{Length}             & \mc{Q}{1.97 m}\\
\mc{P}{Shell diameter}     & \mc{Q}{0.1 m}\\
\mc{P}{Number of baffles}  & \mc{Q}{19}\\
\mc{P}{Baffle spacing}     & \mc{Q}{0.1 m}\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{Reboiler RB-01}\\
%%\toprule
\mc{P}{Specification}      & \mc{Q}{Value}\\
\midrule
\mc{P}{Reboiler type}      & \mc{Q}{Forced circulation}\\
\mc{P}{Thermal fluid}      & \mc{Q}{Steam}\\
\mc{P}{Heat exchange area} & \mc{Q}{\SI{5.45}{\meter\squared}}\\
\mc{P}{Number of tubes}    & \mc{Q}{28}\\
\mc{P}{Length}             & \mc{Q}{2.44 m}\\
\mc{P}{Shell diameter}     & \mc{Q}{0.25 m}\\
\mc{P}{Number of baffles}  & \mc{Q}{23}\\
\mc{P}{Baffle spacing}     & \mc{Q}{0.1 m}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```